# Spring not import all beans implementations from JARs

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

In jar file has interfrace ILogger.
Another jars has implementations ILogger. (Example one.jar:**Logger1**, two.jar:**Logger2**,...)
In main file applicationContext.xml has line:

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/applicationContext.xml"/>
```

And each jar has  local applicationContext.xml with description one bean.
I inject all logger implementattions:

```
@Autowired
List<ILogger> loggers;
```

But list has only one implementation (only **Logger2**).

 If i explicitly indicate beans in main applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="logger1" class="demo.Logger1" />
<bean id="logger2" class="demo.Logger2" />
```

All work very good - list has all beans.
But I do not want to explicitly indicate all implementations.
Is there a solution to my problem?

Comment: You seem to have two resources with the exact same fully qualified name in two separate jars (applicationContext.xml). Don't do that. Only one can be loaded: the first one in the classpath. Give your classes and resources different names. That's what packages are for.

Comment: @JBNizet but my classes has differents names: Logger1.java and Logger2.java. I think that they are in the same package should not cause problems.

Comment: It's not about your classes. It's about your applicationContext.xml resources.

Comment: @JBNizet Oh! Very good. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not have an asterisk after classpath. My worked import:

```
<import resource="classpath*:META-INF/applicationContext.xml"/>
```